# Array Traversal by pointer

Tags: c++

All elements are shifted right by one unit, with the last element wrapping around to the beginning.

[0,1,3,3,4], it would be modified to contain [4,0,1,3,3], however this makes it updated to contain [4,0,3,3,3]

```
void shiftRight(int arr[], int n) {
    int temp = arr[n - 1];
    const int *end = arr + n - 1;
    for (const int *i = end; i > arr; i--) {
       arr[*i] = arr[*i - 1];
    }
    arr[0] = temp;
}
```

The array is improperly updated. What am I doing wrong with the array update?

Comment: Stop using array subscripting if you want to do this with pointers and dereference operator `*` only. When you reach for the `[` or `]` keys, you are deviating from your goal, and it's a sign of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing your pointer to your array with the index:

```
arr[*i] = arr[*i - 1]
```

You are comparing `i` with `arr` which indicates a big mistake!
Your loop is actually:

```
int *end = arr + n - 1;
for (int *i = end; i > arr; i--) {
   *i = *(i - 1);
```

The pointers cannot be `const`, you are modifying your array.

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. So, having the *(i-1) is a redirect in the stack to the position in memory which is what I want rather than what I have which does? Sorry I would just like to make sure that I have this down.

Comment: Yes, it takes the pointer `i` which should be to a position inside your array and gets the element at the position just before. If you had a `double` array instead, you would see that the indirections you are doing in your original code don't compile.

Answer (score 0):

With std, you may simply do:

```
void shiftRight(int arr[], int n) {
    std::rotate(arr, arr + n - 1, arr + n);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Hgdxyt)